# Camera resolution is blurry in some devices in surfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera

I don't understand what the problem with my code. In some devices my camera resolution is fine. But at some devices, my camera resolution is not good.

Here is my class.

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView capture_image_button, camera_image_view, imagecancel, cameraClose;
    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    Camera.ShutterCallback myShutterCallback;
    Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW;
    //Bitmap correctBmp;
    Camera.PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG;
    Button uploadImage;
    private ImageHolder imageHolder;
    public String path;
    int mVinappserial;
    static FetchDocument fetchDocument;
    UtilityOfActivity utilityOfActivity;
    File file;
    Bitmap bm;

    boolean previewing = false;
    public final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 1;
    LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity)
                    this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {


            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }

        }


        myShutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() {

            public void onShutter() {

            }
        };
        myPictureCallback_RAW = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageInByte, Camera arg1) {

            }
        };


        myPictureCallback_JPG = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageInByte, Camera arg1) {

                if (imageInByte != null) {
                    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                    //int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, (imageInByte != null) ? imageInByte.length : 0);
                    float ratio = (float)bm.getWidth() /  (float)bm.getHeight();

                    int screenHeight = (int)(ratio*screenWidth);

                    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                        // Notice that width and height are reversed
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenHeight, screenWidth, true);
                        int w = scaled.getWidth();
                        int h = scaled.getHeight();
                        // Setting post rotate to 90
                        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
                        mtx.postRotate(90);
                        // Rotating Bitmap
                        bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaled, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
                    }else{// LANDSCAPE MODE
                        //No need to reverse width and height
                        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, screenWidth,screenHeight , true);
                        bm=scaled;
                    }
                    //  photoPreview.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
                // isImageCaptured = true;
                //photoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                // surfaceView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                //Bitmap bitmapPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);


             /*   int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(imageInByte);
              //  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, bytes.length);

                switch (orientation) {

                    case 90:
                        bitmapPicture = UtilityOfActivity.rotateImage(bitmapPicture, 90);

                        break;
                    case 180:
                        bitmapPicture = UtilityOfActivity.rotateImage(bitmapPicture, 180);

                        break;
                    case 270:
                        bitmapPicture = UtilityOfActivity.rotateImage(bitmapPicture, 270);

                        break;
                    case 0:
                        // if orientation is zero we don't need to rotate this

                    default:
                        break;
                }*/

                if (bm != null) {

                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDoc");
                    if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                        file.mkdir();
                    }

                    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myDoc",
                            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


                    try {
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        // bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, fileOutputStream);

                        fileOutputStream.flush();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }



               /* try {
                    bitmapPicture = UtilityOfActivity.rotateImageIfRequired(bitmapPicture, file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                //bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, 76, 100, null, true);

                //  correctBmp = UtilityOfActivity.getResizedBitmap(correctBmp, 1000);

                byte[] byteImage = UtilityOfActivity.bitmaptoByteArray(bm);
                imageHolder = new ImageHolder();
                if (byteImage != null) {
                    imageHolder.setImageInByte(byteImage);
                }

                imageHolder.setImageName(file.getName());
                imageHolder.setIsUpload(0);
                imageHolder.setImagePath(file.getAbsolutePath());


                Log.d("", "");
                camera_image_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                imagecancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                camera_image_view.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 120, 150, false));
                capture_image_button.setEnabled(false);
                capture_image_button.setAlpha(0.3f);
                utilityOfActivity.progresDissmiss();


            }
        };

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


        controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        capture_image_button = (ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.capture_image_button);
        camera_image_view = (ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.camera_image_view);
        imagecancel = (ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.imagecancel);
        cameraClose = (ImageView) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.cameraClose);
        uploadImage = (Button) viewControl.findViewById(R.id.uploadImage);
        capture_image_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        imagecancel.setOnClickListener(this);
        cameraClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        if (getIntent() != null) {
            fetchDocument = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Constant.KEY_OBJECT);
            mVinappserial = getIntent().getIntExtra(Constant.KEY_VINAPPSERIAL, 0);
        }
        utilityOfActivity = new UtilityOfActivity(CameraActivity.this);


        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();

        if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            try {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

                camera.startPreview();

                previewing = true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            //params.setRotation(270);//Just add this single line of code***


        } else {

            camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        setCameraDisplayOrientation(this, Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, camera);


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.capture_image_button:
                utilityOfActivity.progressDialogShow("please wait...");

                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.uploadImage: {
                saveImage();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.imagecancel:
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,
                        CameraActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_OBJECT, fetchDocument);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_VINAPPSERIAL, mVinappserial);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            case R.id.cameraClose:

                finish();

                break;
        }

    }

    public void saveImage() {

        if (imageHolder != null) {
            WebRequest webRequest = new WebRequest(this);
            SaveImageRequest saveImageRequest = new SaveImageRequest();
            saveImageRequest.setCalledBy(Constant.Called_by_INSERT);
            saveImageRequest.setDocSerial(Constant.DOC_SERIAL_PROFILE_0);
            saveImageRequest.setNewFileName(imageHolder.getImageName());
            saveImageRequest.setImageData(imageHolder.getImageInByte());
            saveImageRequest.setImagePath(imageHolder.getImagePath());

            saveImageRequest.setDocCode(fetchDocument.getDocTypeCode());
            saveImageRequest.setFetchDocument(fetchDocument);
            saveImageRequest.setVehSerial(mVinappserial);
            webRequest.uploadImageDocument(saveImageRequest, CameraActivity.this);

            //  this.getIntent().addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            //  Intent intent=getIntent();
            // this.finish();
        } else {
            utilityOfActivity.toast(getString(R.string.please_select_image));
        }

    }

    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity, int cameraId, Camera camera) {
        Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                degrees = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                degrees = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                degrees = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                degrees = 270;
                break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {

        this.camera = camera;
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<String> focusModes = parameters.getSupportedFocusModes();
        if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        } else if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
            parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you use the *deprecated* Camera API. If your target devices run Lollipop and higher, consider switching to the modern **camera2** API.

Comment: hey! i am getting the same problem.. have you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, I resolved it by myself.

Comment: could you be a dear and post how you resolved it?